# How set custom 'Content-Disposition' Header in POST request in Java?

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

The server I am sending a POST request to requires extra parameters in the Content-Disposition field that are easily added in C# code, but I am struggling to replicate this functionality in Java.
The working C# code:

```
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent()) {
        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("filepath"));
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "file",
            FileName = "file.zip.encrypted",
        };
        
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("Type", "CSV"));
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("Token", jwt));

        content.Add(fileContent);
 
        var requestUri = "url";

        var result = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
```

When I print the above request headers the Content-Disposition header looks like:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=file.zip.encrypted; Type=CSV; Token=jwt
```

Attempting to replicate this POST request in Java Apache Http:

```
 File file = new File("filepath");

      String headerValue = "form-data; name=file; filename=\"file.zip.encrypted\"; Type=\"CSV\"; Token=\""+jwtToken+"\"";
      
      try (CloseableHttpClient client2 = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        HttpPost post2 = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addPart("file", new FileBody(file)).build();
        post2.setHeader("Content-Disposition", headerValue);
        post2.setEntity(entity);
        try (CloseableHttpResponse response2 = client2.execute(post2)) {
          System.out.println(response2.toString());
        }
      }
```

However, when I print the Headers in this request, only the name and filename fields are captured, and not the other parameters required in the Content-Disposition header. This is leading to Internal Server Error responses, as the Header does not contain the required parameters. (tried with and without the added quotes around field values)

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.zip.encrypted"
```

Any help getting the C# POST request behavior replicated in Java would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: *HttpPost* what is the full-qualified package name of that class please?

Comment: @g00se org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost

Comment: It would appear (according to [this](https://docs.w3cub.com/http/headers/content-disposition.html)) that only those attributes which 'stick' are actually supported

Comment: This section talks about multiple parameters -- [here](https://docs.w3cub.com/http/headers/content-disposition.html#:~:text=Additional%20directives%20are%20case%2Dinsensitive%20and%20have%20arguments%20that%20use%20quoted%2Dstring%20syntax%20after%20the%20%27%3D%27%20sign.%20Multiple%20parameters%20are%20separated%20by%20a%20semi%2Dcolon%20(%27%3B%27)) . The C# implementation handles extra parameters in the header somehow